# Jlist always empty?

Tags: java, swing, compare, jlist, defaultlistmodel

The following code I have first takes lines from a text file and puts it into an array.  After clicking a button, the program will ask the customer's age.  This age is then put into an if/else if block to add movies into a new array that contains age-appropriate movies (ex: if the age is 5 [i realize this is unrealistic], the new array would only contain G-rated movies).  The program should then show a jlist with the age-appropriate movies' titles.  However, the Jlist never updates and remains blank indefinitely.

```
    public class Store extends JFrame {
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField BuyAgeInput;
DefaultListModel BasketModel = new DefaultListModel();
DefaultListModel CatModel=new DefaultListModel();
/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws FileNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Store frame = new Store();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the frame. 
 **/
public Store() throws FileNotFoundException {
    final Movie[] moviearray=new Movie[100];
    //Open file
    final Scanner reader=new Scanner(new File("movies.txt"));
    //Read movies
    for(int j=0;j<moviearray.length;j++)
    {
        if(reader.hasNext())
        {
            moviearray[j]=new Movie();
            moviearray[j].setTitle(reader.nextLine());
            moviearray[j].setNumber(reader.nextInt());
            reader.nextLine();
            moviearray[j].setGenre(reader.nextLine());
            moviearray[j].setYear(reader.nextInt());
            reader.nextLine();
            moviearray[j].setRating(reader.nextLine());
            moviearray[j].setPrice(reader.nextDouble());
            if(reader.hasNextLine())
                reader.nextLine();
        }
    }
    final Movie[] safemovies=new Movie[100];
    setTitle("Title");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    final JPanel StoreWindow = new JPanel();
    StoreWindow.setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Panel.background"));
    StoreWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
    contentPane.add(StoreWindow);
    StoreWindow.setLayout(null);

    final JPanel BuyAge = new JPanel();
    BuyAge.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
    contentPane.add(BuyAge);
    BuyAge.setLayout(null);

    final JPanel BuyWindow = new JPanel();
    BuyWindow.setBounds(0, 0, 434, 262);
    contentPane.add(BuyWindow);
    BuyWindow.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblCashier = new JLabel("Cashier");
    lblCashier.setBounds(48, 50, 71, 28);
    StoreWindow.add(lblCashier);
    lblCashier.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblCashier.setFont(new Font("Perpetua", Font.BOLD, 17));

    JLabel lblCustomer = new JLabel("Customer");
    lblCustomer.setBounds(327, 50, 71, 28);
    StoreWindow.add(lblCustomer);
    lblCustomer.setFont(new Font("Perpetua", Font.BOLD, 17));
    lblCustomer.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    JButton StoreBuy = new JButton("Buy");
    StoreBuy.setBounds(298, 168, 126, 23);
    StoreWindow.add(StoreBuy);

    JLabel lblStorewindow = new JLabel("StoreWindow");
    lblStorewindow.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblStorewindow.setBounds(346, 11, 78, 14);
    StoreWindow.add(lblStorewindow);
    StoreBuy.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(BuyAge);
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    });

    JButton BuyAdd = new JButton("Add");
    BuyAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    BuyAdd.setBounds(10, 194, 89, 23);
    BuyWindow.add(BuyAdd);

    JButton BuyRemove = new JButton("Remove");
    BuyRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        }
    });
    BuyRemove.setBounds(217, 194, 89, 23);
    BuyWindow.add(BuyRemove);

    JButton BuyStore = new JButton("Store (Cancels)");
    BuyStore.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(StoreWindow);
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    BuyStore.setBounds(307, 228, 117, 23);
    BuyWindow.add(BuyStore);

    JButton BuyConfirm = new JButton("Confirm Purchase");
    BuyConfirm.setBounds(78, 228, 117, 23);
    BuyWindow.add(BuyConfirm);

    JLabel lblBuywindow = new JLabel("BuyWindow");
    lblBuywindow.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblBuywindow.setBounds(355, 11, 69, 14);
    BuyWindow.add(lblBuywindow);

    JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_1.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane_1.setBounds(10, 35, 152, 148);
    BuyWindow.add(scrollPane_1);
    final JList catList = new JList(CatModel); {}
    scrollPane_1.setViewportView(catList);


    JScrollPane scrollPane_2 = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane_2.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane_2.setBounds(207, 35, 152, 148);
    BuyWindow.add(scrollPane_2);

    JList buyList = new JList();
    scrollPane_2.setViewportView(buyList);
    buyList.setModel(BasketModel);

    BuyAgeInput = new JTextField();
    BuyAgeInput.setText("Age");
    BuyAgeInput.setBounds(10, 114, 86, 20);
    BuyAge.add(BuyAgeInput);
    BuyAgeInput.setColumns(10);

    final JLabel lblOnlyPutNumbers = new JLabel("Age must contain only numbers.");
    lblOnlyPutNumbers.setVisible(false);
    lblOnlyPutNumbers.setBounds(122, 117, 154, 14);
    BuyAge.add(lblOnlyPutNumbers);

    JButton BuyAConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
    BuyAConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String memberage = BuyAgeInput.getText();
            if(memberage.matches("^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
            {
                lblOnlyPutNumbers.setVisible(true);
            }
            else
            {
                lblOnlyPutNumbers.setVisible(false);
                int customerage=Integer.parseInt(BuyAgeInput.getText());
                    if(customerage<8)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<moviearray.length;i++)
                        {
                            if((moviearray[i]!=null)&&moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("G"))
                            {
                                safemovies[i]=new Movie();
                                safemovies[i]=moviearray[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(customerage<13)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<moviearray.length;i++)
                        {
                            if((moviearray[i]!=null)&&(moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("G")||moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("PG")))
                            {
                                safemovies[i]=new Movie();
                                safemovies[i]=moviearray[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(customerage<17)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<moviearray.length;i++)
                        {
                            if((moviearray[i]!=null)&&(moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("G")||moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("PG")||moviearray[i].getGenre().equals("PG-13")))
                            {
                                safemovies[i]=new Movie();
                                safemovies[i]=moviearray[i];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(customerage>=17)
                    {
                        for(int i=0;i<moviearray.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(moviearray[i]!=null)
                        {
                            safemovies[i]=new Movie();
                            safemovies[i]=moviearray[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                for(int i=0;i<safemovies.length;i++)
                {
                    if(safemovies[i]!=null)
                    {
                        CatModel.addElement(safemovies[i].getTitle());
                    }
                }
                catList.setModel(CatModel);
                getContentPane().removeAll();
                getContentPane().add(BuyWindow);
                validate();
                repaint();
            }   
        }
    });
    BuyAConfirm.setBounds(10, 187, 89, 23);
    BuyAge.add(BuyAConfirm);

    JButton btnStorecancels = new JButton("Store (Cancels)");
    btnStorecancels.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            getContentPane().removeAll();
            getContentPane().add(StoreWindow);
            validate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
    btnStorecancels.setBounds(284, 228, 140, 23);
    BuyAge.add(btnStorecancels);

    JLabel lblPleaseEnterYour = new JLabel("Please enter your age. This will determine which movies you can buy.\r\n");
    lblPleaseEnterYour.setBounds(10, 30, 414, 14);
    BuyAge.add(lblPleaseEnterYour);

    JLabel lblBuyage = new JLabel("BuyAge");
    lblBuyage.setFont(new Font("Arial Black", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    lblBuyage.setBounds(344, 11, 80, 14);
    BuyAge.add(lblBuyage);
}
```

}

(I apologize for the length, but I think this is as minimal as I can get.  I also left the imports out).
This is the code I have for the Movie class:

```
    public class Movie {
public String title;
public int number;
public String genre;
public int year;
public Object rating;
public double price;

public Movie()
{
    title="";
    number=0;
    genre="";
    year=0;
    rating="";
    price=0;
}
public Movie(String t,int n,String g,int y,String r,double p)
{
    title=t;
    number=n;
    genre=g;
    year=y;
    rating=r;
    price=p;
}

public void setTitle(String t)
{
    title=t;
}
public String getTitle()
{
    return title;
}
public void setNumber(int n)
{
    number=n;
}
public int getNumber()
{
    return number;
}
public void setGenre(String g)
{
    genre=g;
}
public String getGenre()
{
    return genre;
}
public void setYear(int y)
{
    year=y;
}
public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}
public void setRating(Object object)
{
    rating=object;
}
public Object getRating()
{
    return rating;
}
public void setPrice(double p)
{
    price=p;
}
public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}
public void addExisting(int x)
{
    number=number+x;
}
public void takeway(int x)
{
    number=number-x;
}
```

}

And here's the format for my movies file:

```
    Now You See Me
    5
    Action
    2013
    PG-13
    10.00
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is no good:

```
if((moviearray[i]!=null)&&moviearray[i].getGenre()=="G")
```

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that == checks if the two *objects* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.  So instead of

```
if (fu == "bar") {
  // do something
}
```

do,

```
if ("bar".equals(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

or,

```
if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(fu)) {
  // do something
}
```

So for your program, do:

```
if((moviearray[i] != null) && 
   moviearray[i].getGenre().equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
```

---

Also your safeMovies collection should be an ArrayList not an array. Your current code, if it worked, would create an array with quite a few null gaps (the moves that aren't G rated), which will cause NullPointerExceptions to occur when you tried to call methods on the array's items. So either use an ArrayList, or else get rid of safeMovies altogether and simply add the Movie to your list's model.

---

Also a nitpick, this line:

```
safemovies[i]=new Movie();
```

is wasted code. You're creating a Movie object only to discard it on the next line -- makes no sense.

---

And another nitpick. This variable, `CatModel`, should be `catModel`. Variable and method names should all begin with a lower-case letter while class names should start with an upper -case letter. Following these and other Java naming and formatting conventions will make your code easier for others (***us!***) to understand.

Comment: Okay, I changed the '==' to '.equalsIgnoreCase' and changed the naming conventions of the variables, but the lists are still coming up blank.  I also created a variable, safeMovieCount, to make sure there aren't null objects between my non-null's in my safemovie array

Comment: I also set catList to catModel again to see if it would update, but sadly it didn't.

Comment: @StantonProgrammer: time for you to consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StantonProgrammer: great, but if you want us to be able to give you a solution, again consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Up to you.

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this site; exactly what should I do? Post an example scenario of what should happen?

Comment: @StantonProgrammer: please click on and read the link in my comment above. It will explain all.

Comment: Okay, I tried to make the code minimal and ready for replication (though I left the imports out).  Sorry for the length, but I think someone wanting to replicate the code would need all of it.

Comment: @StantonProgrammer: can't compile as it's missing a class, Movie, and I can't run it as it's missing a file. Please consider things from our end, and understand that we only have what you give us. Please re-read the link above to see what we require.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. The only thing missing (I think) is the imports.

Comment: I just tried putting in a 'system.out.println(safemovies[i].getTitle());' and it wouldn't get to that line of code.  Is there soemwhere else I should update my model? If so, where?

Comment: @StantonProgrammer: When I run your program, I'm getting the JList filled with data, but it refills it with repeats of the data if I go back into the buy view. It looks like you need to clear your JList's model before trying to refill it. You also should not use absolute positioning since your GUI does not show properly on my platform with many of the texts being cut off. Use the layout managers as they prevent this from happening. And use CardLayout to swap views. Also, yes, you should post imports with your code. Try to make our work easier to do. We're volunteers.